# How to intercept method with ByteBuddy as in CGLIB with MethodInterceptor for calling MethodProxy.invokeSuper(...)

Tags: java, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

I want to intercept some methods with ByteBuddy. 
When i use   `InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(invocationHandler)` i can't invoke super method. Holding object instance is not suitable for my case. I want exactly as in CGLIB like below.

```
(MethodInterceptor)(obj, method, args, proxy)->{
   // to do some work
   Object o = proxy.invokeSuper(obj,args);
   // to do some work
   return o;
}
```

How can i achieve intercepting method in ByteBuddy like this?

I tried `MethodCall` type of `Implemetation` but it not solved my problem. Because i can't manage `MethodCall.invokeSuper()` in this case.

```
.intercept(MethodCall
                        .run(() -> System.out.println("Before"))
                        .andThen(MethodCall.invokeSuper())
                        .andThen(MethodCall
                                .run((() -> System.out.println("After")))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `MethodDelegation`, for example:

```
public class MyDelegation {
  @RuntimeType
  public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> superCall) throws Exception {
    // to do some work
    Object o = superCall.call();
    // to do some work
    return o;
  }
}
```

Then using:

```
.intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyDelegation.class))
```

You can check the javadoc for `MethodDelegation` for more annotations that you can use to inject contextual information.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelWinterhalter! It helped me lot. I used @SuperMethod annotation for getting proxy method. But this method does't contain annotations from original method. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What you mean by annotations? If you want to get hold of a reference of the method being invoked, use the a parameter with @Origin.

Comment: Thanks again! @Origin is exactly what i want.